# django Ajax GET url Not Found

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to pass parameters using Ajax and Django 1.11 and getting the error Not Found: /enquiry/followup_alter/.Here is the code.

Error:

```
    Not Found: /enquiry/followup_alter/
```

Ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".remove").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').hide();
        var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/enquiry/followup_alter/",
            data:"id=" +a_href,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
      });
    })
```

enquiry/urls.py:

```
    url(r'^followup_alter/id=(?P<id>[\d]+)/$', views.followup_alter),
```

views.py:

```
    def followup_alter(request,id):
      get = Followup.objects.get(id = id)
      get.status = 1
      get.save()
      return HttpResponse('Entry Removed')
```

Please help!

Comment: if you're passing `id` as query parameter, I don't think you need to add that pattern to `urls.py`, instead can you could use  something like `id = request.GET['id']`

Comment: put a `?` mark after your url, like this:

`url(r'^followup_alter/?id=(?P<id>[\d]+)/$', views.followup_alter),`

See the answer of @C14L for details

Comment: @sphoenix, I tried that  but didnt work besides what Madhan suggests in upper comment is working fine.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil thanks for the suggestion, I am using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` is sent as a GET parameter, not as part of the URL.

```
type:"GET",
url:"/enquiry/followup_alter/",
data:"id=" +a_href,
```

That should result in `/enquiry/followup_alter/?id=123`.

```
r'^followup_alter/id=(?P<id>[\d]+)/$
```

This expects a URL `/enquiry/followup_alter/id=123`